# Order by number with digits MySql

Tags: mysql

I have field in mysql like:

```
Street_name | number
Wielkopolska | 1
Wielkopolska | 2
Wielkopolska | 2A
Wielkopolska | 3
Wielkopolska | 4A
Wielkopolska | 7/10
Wielkopolska | 10
```

How can I sort it by numer but without this special chars ? Because when I Was sort by DESC its get:

```
Wielkopolska | 1
Wielkopolska | 2
Wielkopolska | 3
Wielkopolska | 10
Wielkopolska | 2A
Wielkopolska | 4A
Wielkopolska | 7/10
```

Anyone knows how sort it naturally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER BY CAST(number as signed)
```

This should give you the correct result

Comment: Working :) Thanks :)